# Hook inside class

Tags: 8

I would like know if it's possible to use hook inside a class and inside .module file.

By example :

modulename.module

```
<?php
use Drupal\xenforo\Xenforo\XenAPI;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
Class XenforoBridgeIntegration {
    // use Drupal 8 hook here and can use OrientedObject inside
}
```

I have try, but hook don't work if it's inside a class ?

Comment: There is an issue for this: https://www.drupal.org/node/1972304 postponed until 8.1.x at this stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Hooks are functions that exist in the global namespace. Class/instance methods cannot be used to implement them.

If you take a look at the very simple [ModuleHandler::invoke](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ModuleHandler.php/function/ModuleHandler%3A%3Ainvoke/8) method, you'll see this in action:

```
public function invoke($module, $hook, array $args = array()) {
  if (!$this->implementsHook($module, $hook)) {
    return;
  }
  $function = $module . '_' . $hook;
  return call_user_func_array($function, $args);
}
```

As you can see, you must have a function called MODULENAME_HOOKNAME available in the global namespace, no consideration is given to classes or namespace resolution.

You can (and probably should) hand off whatever processing you're doing inside the hook to a specific class, but the hook itself will need to be implemented in procedural style.

Comment: If you want to keep your code in classes, you could implement a slim function that calls a service or static method. Payment does that for example, but I personally find that goes too far :)